# MySQL multiple count on the same column and insert the result to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables as follows:

table1

```
id | fullname | gender | level
------------------------------
1  | Jerry    | Male   | Year 1
2  | Jen      | Female | Year 1
3  | Tom      | Male   | Year 2
4  | Natasha  | Female | Year 2
```

table2

```
level | male | female
----------------------
      |      |
      |      |
```

What I want to do is to INSERT the total no. of male and total no. of female from table1 into table2 group by the level.

The expected result supposed to look like the following table:

```
level  | male | female
---------------------
Year 1 |  1   |  1
Year 2 |  1   |  1
```

I've tried the following code:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (level, male, female)
SELECT level,
       SUM(gender = 'Male') male,
       SUM(gender = 'Female') female,
FROM table1
GROUP BY level
```

The above code I got it from one of the question asked here as it seemed to have the same problems as mine BUT when I run the code, it doesn't give me anything.

Is the problem from the tables itself? Or is it from the code?

Comment: THere is a comma after `female`.  I consider this a typographic error and vote to close such questions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just realised about that. Thank you but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: It works. The order of the column were wrong. Sorry for the inconvenient. Thank you again :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (level,male,female) 
SELECT level, 
SUM(CASE WHEN `gender` = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS male, 
SUM(CASE WHEN `gender` = 'female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS female 
FROM `table1` GROUP BY level
```

Comment: Hey. thanks for the response. But I have another problem. I want to update the whole table by replacing INSERT INTO to REPLACE INTO but instead of replacing the contains of the table, it keeps on adding them. I've tried a lot of possibility but it's just gave me the result.

Comment: *gace me the same result

Comment: There's another problem appear. I can update the table but it couldn't insert any new records :(

Comment: @SujiOK, Without looking at your statement and schema of your table, i can not help you much. But i should caution you as you are using **REPLACE INTO**. It is not always best solution. If handled inappropriately, it can do a lot of damage. Read comments [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html). Saying that, I think, You need to make column 'level' in table2 as primary.

Comment: I have solve that problem by just taking the value straight from table 1. I just didn't think of that way earlier. I'm so slow at that. Anyway, thank you from response. I appreciate it so much :))